# Push Notification Over Wifi

Tags: push-notification

I've got a problem that we are hoping there is a simple solution for.

We have a need to allow a push notification to appear on a device when it enters into a certain space.  The space is only going to be about 1500 sq ft.  So my thought is to set up a wifi network in this area... I'm curious if anyone is aware if it is possible to notify anyone with our app installed on their device when they enter into this wifi space if they want to take a certain action... for instance to open the app?

Answer (score 1):

Create an Android service that is launched when the intent WIFI connected is triggered.

The service will check if the bssid of the wifi connection is the same of the wifi area you want to monitor and then it could either launch the app/show popup/show notification.